# How to check if variable from running command is set properly in Bash?

Tags: bash, variables

I have a simple variable like this which I always use in my scripts but since -in this example- it relies on a third-party tool (icanhazip.com in this example) it is not 100% reliable. Either this service can be down for the time being or my VPS may not be able to access it at the moment while let's say Ubuntu is still setting up the network since said VPS has just deployed.

Is there a way to make this more reliable while still using that third-party service? For example adding a way to try running this command over and over until it returns an IP address and not something else? or what other options do I have to make this more reliable? In this example I know I can just try to get my IP address locally (like using `ip a`) and not rely on a third-party service but this is just one example regardless of the command running inside. Could be anything, not just icanhazip.com. Plus doing it this way also tells me that I can access the internet from inside my VPS or wherever I'm running the script containing this piece of code.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

IPv4=$(curl -4 icanhazip.com)
IPv6=$(curl -6 icanhazip.com)

echo $IPv4 - $IPv6
```

Thanks!

Comment: please update the question to include a) the code you're using to *test* the variables, b) an example of wrong/invalid data in the variables and c) correct/valid data in the variables; one 'simple' solution would be a `while true` loop that tests the values, sleeps if not set, and breaks/exits if set ... additionally the loop could exit/abort if a certain amount of time passes and the variables are still not set

Answer (score 1):

You could just put it in a loop, something like (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

getIp() {
    local ver=$1 dur=1 maxIters=10 iters=0 ip regexp stat=0

    if (( ver == 4 )); then
        regexp=your favorite IPV4 regexp
    else
        regexp=your favorite IPV6 regexp
    fi

    ip=$(curl -"$ver" icanhazip.com)
    while [[ ! "$ip" =~ regexp ]]; do
        iters=$(( iters + 1 ))
        if (( iters > maxIters )); then
            echo "like, totally failed, dude" >&2
            stat=1
            break
        fi
        sleep "$dur"
        ip=$(curl -"$ver" icanhazip.com)
        dur=$(( dur * 2 ))
    done

    (( stat == 0 )) && printf '%s\n' "$ip"
    return "$stat"
}

ipv4=$(getIp 4)
ipv6=$(getIp 6)
```

The above will iterate 10 times, doubling the sleep duration each time to give the target site longer and longer to respond before it gives up. Massage to suit.

Google will provide lots of answers for regexps to validate IP addresses in bash, e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/717817/133219.